Circuit Keeps Shorting the Drain - Source of my MOSFET


MOSFET datasheet
Flyback Diode datasheet
I'm trying to control a universal motor with PWM (generated by Raspberry Pi) modulating its speed.  As soon as I switch the power on (115Vac mains), the motor is running wide open, and the MOSFET has been shorted D-S.
I had this exact circuit working great on Friday evening, and after playing around with it Monday, I can't keep my MOSFETs safe suddenly.  I have no idea what changed, or why it was working for a while and now it craps out on me as soon as I switch it on.  I've even totally rebuilt the circuit on another proto-board with brand-new parts.
Right now, I'm not even connecting the VOM1271 because it's shorting without it connected.
With or without the MOSFET in the circuit, I'm getting a 6-7V spike between G-S (of where the MOSFET would be) as soon as I switch it on.
Any ideas on what could be going wrong?  What else can I look at to key in on the problem? Any more info I need to include?
C7 is polarized, BTW, the schematic just doesn't show it.  I've also, obviously, omitted the PWM part of the circuit to help clean it up.
D2 is Zener diode
Max motor current is 5.75A, but after running it wide open, I was only reading around 2A



Please link to the MOSFET data sheet. In the question not the comments

What is the max motor current?

Please show photos of the circuit prototype as well, front side and back side.

Is D1 still OK?  If something killed Q2, then there's a very good chance that D1 got damaged as well.  As far as that goes, I'd check all the semiconductors.  A serious short circuit anywhere could damage just about everything.  D5 could have shorted diodes as well.

The whole circuit has been rebuilt, and I usually replace D1 every time I replace the MOSFET.  I left this one because it seems to be passing all of the tests.  It reads 160ishV across it with the motor and MOSFET out of the circuit.  It reads 0.45V across it in diode mode of the multimeter...

Your construction method is not suitable for this type of circuit - the wires to the mosfet introduce unwanted inductance that most likely cause oscillations when switching.  The gate protection zener  can do nothing as  the inductance is between it and the mosfet.

Can you help me understand what you mean by this?  Are you talking about the schematic, or how I had this soldered?

PV optoisolators are generally not suitable for PWM - they are way too slow.
Probably you're overstressing your MOSFET by switching it too slowly. With an inductive load (especially, but even without) the MOSFET will see high voltage and high current simultaneously for a long time each cycle which can destroy it.
I suggest creating a separate power supply on the mains side and using a logic-output optocoupler driving a gate driver that can switch the MOSFET's gate charge smartly. You can even find the two in one package if you look, but you'll still need to add the power supply.

There are other problems (not your problems right now) than can pop up when you switch the MOSFET too fast- in particular inductance in the source circuit can cause gate driver failure.  Good layout is very important where high currents are being switched quickly. Sometimes a good gate driver is deliberately degraded a bit by adding a series gate   resistor of maybe 15Ω, which results in more controlled switching speed. To a first approximation, MOSFETs switch as quickly as you can supply or drain the gate charge, so getting hundreds of mA or even amperes in and out of that gate quickly is important in dealing with that charge.

Another huge problem is the 1M resistor.

@JonathanS. It probably eats up a few mA of the LED current.

I'm using a 250Hz PWM, is that too slow and putting stress on the MOSFET?  What would be an ideal frequency?  I stuck with the VOM1271 because it didn't require another power supply.  I'm already using one to power my Raspberry Pi, or whatever I end up using here for PWM.  I included the full schematic to give you a better idea.

If the MOSFET has 8nC of gate charge and the opto has average 4uA to get rid of it, that's around 1ms. The MOSFET also looks marginal with motor starting current (probably ~20A) and gate voltage (should be 10V and the opto can manage only maybe 8V, even without the 1MΩ)  and its safe operating area (SOA) does not look generous. Without doing a lot of calculations, too many things look to be marginal.

These are things I didn't know to consider, and likely the source of my issues.  I'll keep plugging away at it.
